# Reversing a 5 digit number gives negative number

Tags: c

This is my program for reversing a number.But when I take 5 digits as input, sometimes the answer is correct and positive and sometimes it's negative.

```
#include<dos.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    clrscr();
    int a,b,c;
    b=0;
    printf("Enter the no");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    c=a;
    while(a>0)
    {
        b=(b*10)+(a%10);
        a=a/10;
    }
    printf("\noriginal no %d",c);

    printf("\nreversed no is %d",b);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

If input:  12111
   output: 11121

input:  22333
   output: -32214

The limit of integer is from -32768 to 32767, then why is the answer negative?
I tried using long but I got my reversed number as 0.

Comment: You have a particularly old implementation of C if your `int` is 2 bytes.

Comment: Why go the hard route of "reversing" the number "mathematically"? Why not just do a character-by-character reverse?

Comment: @Bathsheba Look at the first few lines. This may very well be Turbo C...for MS-DOS.

Comment: If the limit is 32767, then reversing 22333 would yield 33322, which is larger than the limit!!!

Comment: As this is not a mathematical operation (what is the result of reversing `2300` -- and why don't you get this value back from reversing the result again?), you would be far better off with a trivial string reversal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bathsheba mentioned, `sizeof(int)` is apparently 2, and given the headers you're using, the platform is MS-DOS, which means your `int` only has 16 bits of information available. Because the first bit is the sign bit, that leaves you with 15 bits and 2^15 is 32768, meaning your range is -32767..+32767. What you want is an `unsigned int` and `%u` for `scanf` and `printf`. That will allow you to use 0..65535.

Need to be able to handle all 5-digit numbers? Switch to `long` instead (it won't matter if you make it signed or unsigned other than using `%ld` or `%lu` for signed or unsigned respectively), and you will have -2147483648..+2147483647 (signed) or 0..4294967295 (unsigned), which will give you more than enough range for a 5-digit number.

If you have problems with using long and the format is correct for scanf and printf, the problem is in your logic and not your reading of numbers at least.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this is a 16-bit DOS program?  So your `int` is only 16 bits/2 bytes, and your program is overflowing it.

You could try detecting when this condition will happen, and/or use `unsigned` to avoid negative numbers or a `long` instead of `int` to store bigger values (though this program will still output incorrect answers if you overflow).

What's the overall aim?  - Can you just doing it by reversing a string instead?

Comment: The last sentence is the most importanat one. If you need to reveres a sequence of digits then there is no point in converting the number into a (binary) integer and carrying out complex calculations.

Comment: The string approach also avoids undefined behaviour in the case of typing in a number matching `%d` which is outside the range of `int`!

Comment: @adpeace I have something more to after I reverse my number mathematically.Please consider that due to some reason I cannot use string(Even though it came to my mind).

Answer (score 2):

If the limit is 32767, then reversing 22333 would yield 33322, which is larger than the limit!!!

If you want to use `long` instead of `int`, then you should also use `"%ld"` instead of `"%d"`.